# Get Div's attribute values using PHP

Tags: php, php-7

Hi i want to get Div's attribute value from a HTML content without using DOMDocument in PHP. here is my code:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
  <div class='viewBuyButt' onclick="javascript:window.location='https://somelink.com?sdf=fhasldfss';return false;"></div>
HTML;        
?>
```

**OUTPUT Expected:**

```
https://somelink.com?sdf=fhasldfss
```

I tried with:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/<div class="viewBuyButt".*\sonclick="(.*?)">/';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $viewAllLink);
var_dump($viewAllLink);// but not getting output
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you can't use `DOMDocument`?

Comment: What is wrong with DOM? It is intended to do this. RegExp is not a big hammer and if it is, not everything is a nail. Anyways, you can go with SimpleXML or XMLReader as an alternative. [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: i have that option tried and its working. So i wanted to know if any other option which may be useful. Thanks for the help

Comment: the quotes must be the same, can't you see

Comment: dont use regex for parsing html, the world will likely explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class='viewBuyButt' onclick="javascript:window.location='https://1.com';return false;"></div>
<div class='No-viewBuyButt' onclick="javascript:window.location='https://mahdiy.ir';return false;"></div>
<div class='viewBuyButt' >onclick="javascript:window.location='https://2.com';return false;"></div>
<div class='viewBuyButt' onclick="javascript:window.location='http://3.com';return false;"></div>
HTML;

preg_match_all("/class='viewBuyButt'((?!(\>|\<)).)*location='(.*)'/", $html, $viewAllLink);
print_r( $viewAllLink );
```

Comment: could you pls add class name also in the preg_match, its critical for me. It should only get location attribute of div with **class=viewBuyButt**

Comment: @Ravistm Code updated! now match tags with **bold**class=viewBuyButt**bold**